# Why does Option.apply throw NPEs for boxed primitives?

Tags: scala

For example, the following code will throw an NPE:

```
val badData = null: java.lang.Long
val boom: Option[Long] = Option(badData)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at scala.Predef$.Long2long(Predef.scala:358)
  ... 33 elided
```

This makes it difficult to work with Java APIs that return boxed primitives.

Note that in this silly example it's possible to just remove the type declaration from `boom` and the code will run without error, but in a more realistic example that may not be possible/easy. For example:

```
MyCaseClass(record getValue m.ID, Option(record getValue m.USER))
```

where record is pulling data from an external source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that on your second line `boom` is declared as a Scala Long therefore an implicit typecast takes place from `java.lang.Long` to `Long`, hence the NPE.

Just make sure you are using the correct Java Long or Scala Long types and that the implicit type conversion won't be invoked. So `MyCaseClass` should have `Option[java.lang.Long]` as its type. If you would like to work around this you can just explicitly type it before calling the `Option.apply` and then map it to the correct Scala type:

`MyCaseClass(Option(badData: java.lang.Long).map(_.toLong))`

Here's my REPL code:

```
scala> val badData = null: java.lang.Long
badData: Long = null

scala> val boom: Option[Long] = Option(badData)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at scala.Predef$.Long2long(Predef.scala:358)
  ... 33 elided

scala> val boom: Option[java.lang.Long] = Option(badData)
boom: Option[Long] = None

scala> case class MyCaseClass(l: Option[Long])
defined class MyCaseClass

scala> MyCaseClass(Option(badData: java.lang.Long).map(_.toLong))
res3: MyCaseClass = MyCaseClass(None)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, although it's annoying that the compiler isn't smart enough to handle that on it's own.